AWS WAF - how to find counted rules in cloudwatch logs?
I'm introducing WAF into my AWS load balancer for the first time to improve the security of my website.
I planned to run it in "count" mode for a while so I could analyse and find false positives before turning it on for real and blocking requests.
I have added two of the AWS managed rulesets and set them to COUNT, rule JSON as follows:
{
  "Name": "ECSAWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet",
  "Priority": 10,
  "Statement": {
    "ManagedRuleGroupStatement": {
      "VendorName": "AWS",
      "Name": "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
    }
  },
  "OverrideAction": {
    "Count": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSetMetric"
  }
}

{
  "Name": "ECSAWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet",
  "Priority": 11,
  "Statement": {
    "ManagedRuleGroupStatement": {
      "VendorName": "AWS",
      "Name": "AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet"
    }
  },
  "OverrideAction": {
    "Count": {}
  },
  "VisibilityConfig": {
    "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
    "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
    "MetricName": "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSetMetric"
  }
}

If I look at "top 10 rules" widget in the Traffic Overview tab in the AWS WAF console I can see various counts popping up for different rules, so I want to find them in cloudwatch to view request details. However when I try to filter by count it never finds any? Using this query:
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter webaclId = "redacted"
| filter action = "COUNT"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20


Do you get any CloudWatch entries for WAF, e.g. by omitting the filter clauses? See also https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/analyzing-aws-waf-logs-in-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/

if I omit the filter or change it to action = ALLOW I see lots of requests, so I'm just confused about why the counted requests aren't showing up

try to add | parse @message ',"nonTerminatingMatchingRules":[{"ruleId":"*","action":"*"' as rule, action

ah that did make them show, so I guess the issue with my filter was that the overall request gets set to ALLOW even though the rule sets the COUNT action

When I came here I didn't check the comments but I finally found the answer myself, and then I saw the comments. To prevent other users such mistakes, here is the answer to find all the counted actions:
fields @timestamp, @message
| parse @message ',"nonTerminatingMatchingRules":[{"ruleId":"*","action":"*"' as rule, action
| filter action = "COUNT"
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20

